# XQuery Update - Add new node to group nodes

Tags: xquery, xquery-update

I have an XML file with following structure -

```
<Root>
   <Doc>
    <Ref>
      <A></A>
      <B></B>
      <A></A>
      <B></B>
      <B></B>
      <B></B>
    </Ref>
   </Doc>  
   <Doc>
    <Ref>
      <A></A>
      <B></B>
      <B></B>
      <B></B>
    </Ref>
   </Doc>  
   <Doc>
    <Ref>
      <A></A>
      <B></B>
      <B></B>
      <A></A>
      <B></B>
      <B></B>
    </Ref>
   </Doc>  
</Root>
```

The node `A` and all simultaneous nodes`B` needs to grouped like

```
<Root>
   <Doc>
    <Ref>
      <data>
        <A></A>
        <B></B>
      </data>
      <data>          
        <A></A>
        <B></B>
        <B></B>
        <B></B>
      </data>
    </Ref>
   </Doc>  
   <Doc>
    <Ref>
      <data>
       <A></A>
       <B></B>
       <B></B>
       <B></B>
      </data>     
    </Ref>
   </Doc>  
   <Doc>
    <Ref>
      <data>
       <A></A>
       <B></B>
       <B></B>
      </data>
      <data>   
       <A></A>
       <B></B>
       <B></B>
      </data>    
    </Ref>
   </Doc>  
</Root>
```

The number of nodes `B`, after node `A` can be anything, like 2, 3 ... or 10..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what do you mean by "simultaneous"? Looks to me like you want to group together all `<A/>` elements with following `<B/>`until the next `<A/>` element appears. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: @dirkk - yes correct interpretation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to process such structures is with a 'tumbling window clause'. This will nicely organize the data in the groups that you want. I'll leave it up to you to figure out the exact xquery-update syntax required.

```
for $ref in //Ref
return <Ref>{
  for tumbling window $w in $ref/element()
    start $s when $s/self::A
  return <data>{$w}</data>
  }</Ref>
```